# build_native.py fails with error: Build dynamic library for project .. fails

Tags: android, python, cocos2d-x

I have already installed cocos2d-x 3.0 and try to build an android version but when I run ./build_native.py, it was failed with error

```
File "./build_native.py", line 89, in do_build
raise Exception("Build dynamic library for project [ " + app_android_root + " ] fails!")
Exception: Build dynamic library for project [ /Users/hoangha/Desktop/Enigma/cocos2d-x-3.0/projects/2048-enhanced-version/source/proj.android ] fails!
```

I have read the line 89 in the build_native.py

```
if os.system(command) != 0:
    raise Exception("Build dynamic library for project [ " + app_android_root + " ] fails!")
```

But I don't understand command os.system(command) in python, so can anybody help me to fix this error.

Comment: There's nothing to go on here, we need more info. The exception message alone is too generic. PS: a common source of problems is having the project in a path that has a space somewhere, the cocos2dx tools can't handle spaces in paths/filenames.

Comment: I am getting the same issue. This is the statement it throws before building the stack trace
Please input the absolute/relative path of ".keystore" file:
I am building the cocos2d-x generated project in Win 8.1 in Eclipse Luna

Comment: I am getting the same error. has anyone fixed this already?

Comment: `os.system(comand)` runs whatever is in the `command` variable in your system's command line. Can you get the value of this variable?

Comment: Have you added the paths of your scenes to the Android.mk file in the jnk subfolder in proj.android folder